# Drupal Commerce Paypal WPP Programatically Create a Transaction

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I stumbled on a thread over at: https://drupal.org/node/1867768 and I am trying to do a similar integration with a "one page checkout" where the customer selects the product, puts in shipping information and cc information all on one page and I'm capturing that info using drupal's form api submit callback. I can programmatically create the order, add the profile type to the order but I'm getting a little stuck when it comes to the transaction. By the looks of it Ryan had mentioned that each payment gateway has a different way of declaring the transaction. I'm using Paypal Payments pro also know and Website Payments Pro (WPP) and was wondering how to go about creating a WPP transaction programmatically and seeing if anyone had dealt with this before?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue.  Instead of retyping it, the answer can be found on drupal.org at this link: https://drupal.org/node/1867768#comment-8755925

Comment: Hello @tthenne, please, can you add the code that you are using in your custom module?